# Find the probability density function of the joint pdf $2(x+y)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables for which the joint probability density function (p.d.f) is as follows:

$f(x,y) = \binom{2(x+y) \space \space for \space \space 0\le x \le y \le 1}{0 \space \space \space \space otherwise}$
Find the p.d.f of $Z = X + Y$

My workings:

Given that $Z = X + Y$ then $Z - t = t$ where $t$ denotes $X$ or $Y$, now it can be seen that $0\le Z-t \le t \le 1$ (Although can it be shown that $0 \le Z-t \le t \le z \le 1?$) Given that $0 \le z \le1$ then $z$ can be positive for any value from $Z-1 \le t \le z$

Substituting $f(x, y) = 2(x+y)$ for $f(z) = 2z$

When integrating:

$\int^z_{z-1} 2z dz$

However this is wrong and the lower bound should be $\frac{z}{2}$ what am I missing here?

Comment: Important safety tip. You shouldn't have the same variable as your (dummy) variable of integration, and in the limits of your integration. If you persist with that error you will be in for a miserable time.

Comment: @Glen_b You know me too well! getting over this hurdle will prove beneficial for my future abilities

Comment: As always: **draw the picture** of the integration region.